# KDB: How to Delete rows from Partitioned Table

Tags: partition, kdb

I have the below query used to delete rows from a partitioned table, but it doesn't work. What is the approach used for deleting rows in a partitioned table?

```
delete from SecurityLoan where lender=`SCOTIA, date in inDays, portfolio in portfoliolist
```

Note that `inDays` and `portfoliolist` are lists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly different method that re-indexes a column in a partition to a new list of indices that you want to keep in that column.

It still follows the same semantics of reading a column in, amending and then resetting it back to disk, just uses a slightly different approach. However, by doing it this way you can grab the indices you want to remove, simply by using a qsql query. It then grabs the full list of indices in a partition, and runs 'except' against the initial list, resulting in the ones you actually want to keep.

It becomes powerful when all you want to do is delete the contents of a sql query from a database/table (as is the case in yours).

```
// I've commented this function as much as possible to break it down and explain the approach
// db is where the database lives (hsym)
// qry is the qsql query (string)
q)delFromDisk:{[db;qry]
    // grab the tree from the query
    q:parse qry; 
    // cache partition counts
    .Q.cn `. t:q 1;
    // grab i by partition for your qry using the where clause
    d:?[t;raze q 2;{x!x}1#f:.Q.pf;enlist[`delis]!1#`i];
    // grab full indice list for each partition
    a:1!flip (f,`allis)!(`. f;til each .Q.pn t);
    // run except on full indice list and your query's indice list
    r:update newis:allis except'delis from a,'d;
    // grab columns except partition domain
    c:cols[t] except .Q.pf;
    // grab partitions that actually need modifications and make them dir handles
    p:update dirs:.Q.par[db;;t] each p[.Q.pf] from p:0!select from r where not allis~'newis;
    // apply on disk to directory handle (x), on column (y), to new indices (z)
    m:{@[x;y;@;z]};
    // grab params from p
    pa:`dirs`c`newis#p cross ([]c);
    // modify each column in a partition, one partition at a time
    m .' value each pa
    };

// test data/table
q)portfolio:`one`two`three`four`five;
q)lender:`user1`user2`user3`user4;
q)n:5;
// set to disk in date partitioned format
q)`:./2017.01.01/secLoan/ set .Q.en[`:./] ([]lender:n?lender;portfolio:n?portfolio);
q)`:./2017.01.02/secLoan/ set .Q.en[`:./] ([]lender:n?lender;portfolio:n?portfolio);
// load db
q)\l .
// lets say we want to delete from secLoan where lender in `user3 and portfolio in `one`two`three
// please note, this query does not have a date constraint, so it may be an inefficient query if you where-clause produces large results. Once happy with the util as a whole, it can be re-jigged to select+delete per partition
q)select from secLoan where lender in `user3,portfolio in `one`two`three
date       lender portfolio
---------------------------
2017.01.01 user3  one
2017.01.01 user3  two
2017.01.02 user3  one
// 3 rows need deleted, 2 from first partition, 1 from second partition
// 10 rows exist
q)count secLoan
10

// run delete function
q)delFromDisk[`:.;"select from secLoan where lender in `user3,portfolio in `one`two`three"];
// reload to see diffs
q)\l .
q)count secLoan
7
// rows deleted
q)secLoan
date       lender portfolio
---------------------------
2017.01.01 user2  five
2017.01.01 user4  three
2017.01.01 user2  three
2017.01.02 user2  five
2017.01.02 user2  two
2017.01.02 user4  three
2017.01.02 user1  five

// PS - can accept a delete qsql query as all the function does is look at the where clause
// delFromDisk[`:.;"delete from secLoan where lender in `user3,portfolio in `one`two`three"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't use delete directly on a partitioned database.

For you to completely remove a row you'd have to read, modify and write all the data down again.

For an example on how to achieve this see the wiki:

http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:KdbplusForMortals/partitioned_tables#1.3.5_Modifying_Partitioned_Tables

Thanks,
Seán